# plugin add action hook is not working :

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to add an custom action hook in wordpress but it's not working.Please help me through this.

```
<?php
function wp_add_google_link(){
global $WP_Admin_Bar;
var_dump($WP_Admin_Bar);
$WP_Admin_Bar->add_menu(array(
'id'=>'google_analytics',
'title'=>'GoogleAnalytics',
'href'=>'https://google.com/analytics'
));
}
add_action('wp_before_admin_bar_render','wp_add_google_link');
```

Comment: Are you sure that the function was not executed?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is working but returning NULL value with an error. It is because `wp_admin_bar` should be lower case. But you are using `WP_Admin_Bar`.

Please check the reference:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Admin_Bar

and

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_before_admin_bar_render

```
function wp_add_google_link(){

global $wp_admin_bar;
var_dump($wp_admin_bar);
$wp_admin_bar->add_menu(array(
'id'=>'google_analytics',
'title'=>'GoogleAnalytics',
'href'=>'https://google.com/analytics'
));
}
add_action('wp_before_admin_bar_render','wp_add_google_link');
```

Screenshot of result

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but i have also used it. but it's also not working.

Comment: What result are you getting? I have shared a screenshot showing my result

Comment: Can you please try installing twentysixteen theme and paste the code in functions.php file to check if it is working or not?

Comment: Thanks a lot, but can you clarify why it's not working when i add this function with the php file of newly created plugin.@Kiran Dash

Comment: This might be having some conflict with your code. May be some error. Check for errors by turning WP_DEBUG true. Or, If you can share the entire code then may be I can help.